# gazebo ros pid plugin

Tags: control, ros, pid, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am looking for a gazebo ros plugin to simulate pid position control.
I found a [GazeboRosForce](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins/Tutorials/Attaching%20a%20GazeboRosForce%20pugin%20to%20Objects%20in%20Simulation) but nothing to rotate or move a joint to a certain position.

Any ideas?

Greetings
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12317/gazebo-ros-pid-plugin/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2011-12-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Adding%20a%20PID%20to%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) is how I've always seen it done. You *could* write a Gazebo plugin, but you could also run a node like this instead, without having to write any new code at all. Running this controller outside of Gazebo will basically subscribe to the joint's positions and then issue corrective commands to force the joint to follow the PID. Whether it's running in a separate node or as a plugin to Gazebo, it's really all the same in terms of functionality.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2011-12-13**:
Good idea thanks, I will try the control_toolbox, If I have the time I will write a gazebo plugin, because a note runs as a separate process while a gazebo plugin will run within the gazebo loop. Therefore you can not assure real-time "as far as you can speak of real-time with a simulator"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Max,

Do you *require* it being a gazebo plugin?. If you can settle for a controller implementing the pr2_controller_interface, the [JointPositionController](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointPositionController) class implements a single-joint PID position controller. Also, some time ago I extended the JointPositionController to a group of joints for convenience reasons ([code](https://github.com/pal-robotics/reem_controllers), not tested extensively). A word of caution: In these implementations updating the reference signal is non-realtime (plain ROS topic).

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2011-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2011-12-13**:
Thank you,  But I am looking for a gazebo plugin! I don't think it makes much sense to use a ROS note, it has to run within gazebo to simulate a pid controller.